# Selecting which object to align to in Powerpoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, alignment

When doing an alignment in Powerpoint 2007 (say, Align Center), is there any way to select which object will be aligned to? It seems to pick one of the objects, but I'm not sure how it decides which one to pick and how to change it. Order of selection and front/back ordering seems to have no effect.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You may be interested in casting your vote to this proposal: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/ba2307e4-ec14-ee11-a81c-000d3ae5b6f4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is Align Vertically or Horizontaly, it puts both objects in the middle of delta between them. If it is Left or Top or values like that, it uses the X-most value to align the other object(s). So if you have a shape that is one inch from the top and another that is 5 inches from the top, it will align the 5-inch one to the 1-inch (the "Top Most").

Comment: Thanks May. It's a pity that "align to left/top/right/bottom most" is the only option, since I find it quite limiting, but if that's all they've implemented, just have to work within it.

Answer (score 1):

A team from the UK created an unobtrusive add-in to provide the ability to hold Shift or Ctrl while aligning to align everything to the first shape selected.

They wrote it for PowerPoint 2003 but it works in PowerPoint 2016 for Windows.  See http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/anchor.html.  It's distributed as an MSI so take precautions against malware.  (I've had no bad effects.)

Comment: Does it work for you on newer version of PowerPoint?

Comment: There seems to be a feature request on PowerPoint: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/ba2307e4-ec14-ee11-a81c-000d3ae5b6f4.

Answer (score 0):

Align top: It picks the highest top and aligns everything to that.
Align bottom It picks the lowest bottom and aligns everything to that.
Much the same for align left and right.
Distribute horizontal: It picks the leftmost edge and the rightmost edge as the overall distance. It keeps those objects fixed and moves the ones in between so that the gap between them is the same.
Much the same for distribute vertical.
Not sure about align middle and center.